# index.html not loading in single-spa-angular application

Tags: angular, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I have a scenario where I need to load a script and external style (css file) in application. single-spa-angular application.

Am trying to add the script and style link in index.html. unable to load the scripts and styles, since index.html is not loading.

```
(main.ts) main-single-spa.ts - const lifecycles = singleSpaAngular({
  bootstrapFunction: singleSpaProps => {
    singleSpaPropsSubject.next(singleSpaProps);
    return platformBrowserDynamic(getSingleSpaExtraProviders()).bootstrapModule(AppModule);
  },
  template: '<app-root />',
  Router,
  NavigationStart,
  NgZone,
});

export const bootstrap = lifecycles.bootstrap;
export const mount = lifecycles.mount;
export const unmount = lifecycles.unmount;

Index.html - <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>app</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/cdn/static/styling/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add script or styles (external files) on the angular.json instead of index.html? I'm not sure, but you need to try.

Comment: @AfifAlfiano Here the question is why the index.html is not loaded while the entry is made in angular.json , however singlespa.main.ts is also added it only loads singlespa.main.ts not going to index.html

Comment: A single-spa MFE doesn't use index.html at all.  Only the root config project provides the index file.  Your MFE is configured to be imported as a pure JS module.  You might want to review single-spa's documentation on the basics on how it works, as it will clear things up for you.  Cheers.